# jQuery: Prevent Select List from turning green on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

This is probably pretty strange but I have a form page with various elements that are being checked for validation when I hit submit. Unfortunately I also have a management side of the page that performs its own Ajax actions.

One of these items has a select list that when I select an option it turns green. I don't really need/want the green validation on this select list as it isn't tied to my postback action at all.

Any ideas on how to turn it off with jQuery? (I'm currently just using $("#form").validate({ ... ...}) to validate my other fields and I think it is taking over for this element too)

Current Validation:

```
$(function () {
    // Validation
    $("#edit-opp-prod-form").validate({
        // Rules for form validation
        rules: {
            Opportunity: {
                required: true
            },
            CommissionAmount: {
                required: true,
                currency: ["", false]
            }
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages: {
            Opportunity: {
                required: "An Opportunity name is required."
            },
            ComissionAmount: {
                required: "A Commission Amount must be set."
            }
        },

        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });

});
```

The Select List I don't want to be validated,

```
<section class="col col-5">
    <div>
        @Html.Label("ProductID", "Products", new { @class = "label" })
        @Html.Action("ProductSelectList", "Products", new { unmappedProducts = true})
    </div>
</section>
```

This produces this when I inspect,

```
<select id=ProductID" name="ProductID">Products</label>
    <option value="...">...</option>
    ...
    <option value="...">...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you put some code in the question?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad That's part of my problem actually. I can't figure out which code is defaulting every form element to auto validate.

Comment: If you can put it here, we can help you to figure it out. :) most likely it is firing onselect event

Comment: @PratikGaikwad This is all I can think of to throw in :/ hopefully it helps clarify.